# How to set an image for menu icon for "BottomNavigationView", as it's displaying only image's design i.e. structure....?

Tags: java, android, android-menu, androiddesignsupport, android-bottomnav

I want to set an particular image to my **BottomNavigationView**'s **menu item**, as when I set an image using drawable, its not working properly.

Can you also guide me as how to display back buttton for an activity...?

Here's my code.

selectedActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".selectedJokesActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="454dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

selectedActivity.xml

[image]

screenshot of my activity:-

[Real device: Android Oreo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uGat.jpg)

menu/navigation.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/digital"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

</menu>
```

Please help....

Comment: Can please explain what is the exact issue?

Comment: @Chirag Savsani : As I am setting particular image in my menu icon in **navigation.xml**, it is not showing it as expected, as its only displaying image's shadow in navigation menu, as you can see in above image.

Comment: You are checking in xml desing tab, can you check in real device and upload screen shot as well, Also which size of image you try to add at navigation menu.xml

Comment: I added my real device's screenshot, as it's of Moto X4- Android Oreo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get actual color or structure of your icon image use this:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to set back button only at the action bar...?

Just add below line in `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will work...!

```
Menu BVMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
BVMenu.setItemIconTintList(null);
BVMenu.findItem(R.id.Your_action_Name).setIcon(Drawable_Name);
```